# Performing Tasks in the background using NSThread

Tags: ios

I want to have a background thread that will check for updates on the server every 5 minutes and process that data.
Should I use NSThread to detach a new thread and run an infinite loop and sleep that loop for every 5 minutes? and where should the thread start from, app delegate?

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `NSThread` like you mentioned, but instead of having an infinite loop with sleeps, you'd be better off using an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).  You can initialize it with `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` and then schedule it on the run loop your background thread.

Comment: great, thanks. Where should the thread be started? in app delegate

Comment: @iosdevnyc - assuming you plan to leave the thread running for the life of the app, that's a reasonable place.  if the thread will only run while a particular view is loaded, i'd start it from the view controller for that view.

Comment: great thanks, yes the thread will be running for the life of the app